# Why doesn't the Gauss-Newton method diverge around the minimum?

Tags: convergence-divergence, optimization, approximation, least-squares, numerical-optimization

I am having trouble visualizing the convergence of the Gauss-Newton method. Consider the simple function of $f(x) = x^2 + 1$. If I try to use the Gauss-Newton method to find the minimum of $f(x)^2$ (which is clearly at $x = 0$), and say the current guess is $\hat{x} = 0.1$, my understanding is that the Gauss-Newton method would approximate $f(x)$ with $\hat{f}(x) = 0.2x + 1.01$, and find $\text{arg}\min_x\hat{f}(x)^2$ instead, which is at $x = -5.05$. This new estimation is clearly worse than the original $x = 0.1$. How can Gauss-Newton converge on simple functions like this one if it seems to diverge every time it gets close to the minimum?

Comment: Using Gauss Newton on a single function just reduces to Newton's method for finding a zero of $f$. Since $f'(0) = 0$, I would not expect it to behave well. The general idea behind Gauss Newton is to minimise the sum of squares of many functions in the hope that the Gauss Newton term will approximate the Hessian in some reasonable way.

Answer (score 1):

The Gauss-Newton method is just the Newton method applied to functions of the form $\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^nr_i^2(x)$, where the Hessian is approximated by first derivatives only. We have
\begin{align}
 f(x)=(1+x^2)^2=x^4+2x^2+1=\frac{1}{2}\left[(\sqrt{2}x^2)^2+(2x)^2+(\sqrt{2})^2\right].
\end{align}
The Gauss-Newton method gives:
\begin{align}
         \mathbf{r}&=[\sqrt{2}x^2,~2x,~\sqrt{2}],\\
  \nabla\mathbf{r}&=[2\sqrt{2}x,~2,~0],\\
  (\nabla f)(x)&=\sum_{i=1}^3r_i\nabla r_i = 4x(x^2+1),\\
   (\nabla^2 f)(x)&\approx \sum_{i=1}^3\nabla r_i\nabla r_i = 4(2x^2+1)~~~~(\text{G.-N.~approximation}),
\end{align}
therefore
\begin{align}
 x_{k+1}=x_k-\frac{(\nabla f)(x)}{(\nabla^2 f)(x)}=x_k-\frac{x_k(x_k^2+1)}{2x_k^2+1}=\frac{x_k^3}{2x_k^2+1}.
\end{align}
which iterates fast to $0$:
\begin{align}
 \text{iter} = 0, x &= 0.1\\
 \text{iter} = 1, x &= 0.0009803921568627453\\
 \text{iter} = 2, x &= 9.423205230889076\text{E}-10\\
 \text{iter} = 3, x &= 8.367504403129781\text{E}-28\\
\end{align}

Comment: It appears that the difference in your formulation is the decomposition of $(1 + x^2)^2$ into $\frac{1}{2}[(\sqrt{2}x^2)^2 + (2x)^2 + (\sqrt{2})^2]$. Does the Gauss-Newton method require such decomposition? If I simply let $n = 1, r_1(x) = 1 + x^2$, would it still converge then?

Comment: The Gauss-Newton method is defined through the specific Hessian approximation (otherwise it is Newton). If you rewrite the minimized function to the form $\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^3 r_i^2(x)$, then you know that this approximation equals exactly to $\sum_{i=1}^3 \nabla r_i \nabla r_i$. This is the only reason why I have rewritten $f(x)$ into this form.